# Unable to get local issuer certificate using CURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm getting the following error when call the CURL with https url:

> "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

```
    $ch = curl_init($sendurl);                                                                                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) .'/cert/uat.abc.pem');

    echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
```

Does anyone know how to set it up?

Comment: Try using the latest `cacert.pem` from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem - adjust / edit the path according in your curl request

Comment: You can disable certificate verification by: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

Comment: We did not want use the open CA, we need to use own cert.

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false) is not safety. we need to verify ssl cer

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set CURLOPT_SSLCERT option to fix it,or use curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1) and curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false) to ignore this warming