# resolve " SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" with httr

Tags: r, curl, httr, rcurl

I know that there are many similar questions out there, e.g.

- [Unable to get local issuer certificate using CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264938/unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-using-curl)
- [SSL errors using MailChimp's API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973701/ssl-errors-using-mailchimps-api/29649024#29649024)

but I'm having trouble finding my way through the answers and applying them to my specific case.  Here's my MCVE:

```
library(httr)
url <- "http://www.ece.mcmaster.ca/~shirani/"
res <- try(http_status(GET(url,timeout(30))))
```

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>     SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I'm pretty sure that this means the remote webserver is using a certificate that my system doesn't recognize. I believe there are two solutions, (1) tell `httr`/`RCurl`/curl to ignore the problem and operate in insecure mode (command line flag `-k`/`--insecure`) or (2) get and store an appropriate certificate somewhere.

### setting 'insecure' options/ignoring the problem

An answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264938/unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-using-curl) suggests (for PHP)

> use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1)` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)`

`?httr:config()` suggests

> Generally you should only need to use this function to set CURL
>        options directly if there isn't already a helpful wrapper
>        function, like set_cookies, add_headers or
>        authenticate. To use this function effectively requires some
>        knowledge of CURL, and CURL options. Use httr_options to see a
>        complete list of available options. To see the libcurl
>        documentation for a given option, use curl_docs.

How would I go about putting this advice in practice?

`httr_options()` provides

```
206             ssl_verifyhost             CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  integer
207             ssl_verifypeer             CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  integer
```

but

```
res <- try(http_status(GET(url,timeout(max_time),
           config=list(ssl_verifyhost=0, ssl_verifypeer=0))))
```

gives the same error (as does including `ssl_verifystatus=0`, the only other `ssl_*` option I see).

### obtaining the correct certificates, or hassling the web site maintainer

If I would rather do things correctly and not ignore the problems. How would I go about (1) identifying what certificate I need, (2) installing it on my system/using it within `httr` (I'm on Linux PopOS 18.04), (3) coherently communicating with the web site maintainer if they should update their certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `config` wrong.  This seems to work:

```
res <- http_status(GET(url,config(ssl_verifypeer=0)))
```

I would still be interested in a more principled solution (i.e., figuring out how to install and deploy the correct certificates).